# Span Question involving selecting statements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $x, y, z$ be vectors and suppose $w = 24x - 24y -6z$ .

If $z = 3x-3y$, then $w = _ + _$. Select the statements that must be true.

A . $Span(y, z) = Span(w,z)$

B . $Span(x, y, z) = Span(w,y,z)$

C . $Span(w, z) = Span(w,y)$

D . $Span(y, w) = Span(x,y)$

E .$Span(y, z) = Span(x,z)$

I have realised that $z$ and $w$ are scalar multiples of each other.
I have attempted to solve this problem by trying to check for the general cases and I think that option B and option D seems to work since I have that $Span(y, w) = Span(x,y)$ so I think D works for this and B follows a similar argument since working the RHS, I have $Span(w, y, z) = Span(z, y) = Span(x, y, z)$. However, I am not sure if I am correct as I do not feel confident with my answers. I hope someone can help me? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be the field that you are working with,

A. Since $z$ and $w$ are scalar multiples of each other, $\operatorname{span}\{w,z\}=Fz$. But, in general, this will be different from $\operatorname{span}\{y,z\}$.

B. Since $z$ and $w$ are scalar multiples of each other and since $z=3x-3y$, $\operatorname{span}\{w,y,z\}=\operatorname{span}\{y,z\}=\operatorname{span}\{x,y,z\}$.

C. Since $z$ and $w$ are scalar multiples of each other, $\operatorname{span}\{w,z\}=Fw$, which, in general, is different from $\operatorname{span}\{w,y\}$.

D. Since $w=6x−6y$, this is true.

E. Since $z=3x−3y$, this is also true.

Comment: Thanks for this, so the only one I was missing was E it seems. I worked on this question for a few hours and you make it seem so easy. Could you perhaps direct me to any material that can make me understand this topic better since the only way I was able to arrive at B and D being true was by "brute forcing" the problem?

Comment: I don't know any. You get used to this after solving a certain number of exercises.